# Minimal surface finite differences problem - Matlab assemble

Tags: matlab, finite-difference, nonlinear-equations, discretization, nonconvex

I face to the following problem:

$$(1+u_x^2)u_{yy} - 2u_xu_yu_{xy} + (1+u_y^2)u_{xx}=0.$$ Problem needs to be discretized and assembled.
Does anybody know how to proceed in Matlab?

Comment: Have you checked _Concus, Paul. "Numerical solution of the minimal surface equation." Mathematics of Computation (1967): 340-350._? [JSTOR link](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2003235)

Comment: What makes the problem more difficult in <put your language here>?

Comment: @nicoguaro in <Matlab> ... nothing more difficult - I guess it is same difficulty, I am just confused... after assemble, do I end up with one matrix and following system Ax = b? (I know - stupid question - I am really newbie in PDE and discretization in general)... also, afterwords - I need to obtain hessian and gradient - do u have any suggestions?

Comment: Hessian of gradient of what function? Have you solved any PDE using finite differences before?

Comment: TR solver? If that's your functional, then those are your gradient and Hessian.

Comment: You should first program Finite Difference for a simpler problem then, what about $\nabla^2 u = 0$.

Comment: I have tried today, this one is working - at least it seems like.  Problem is arriving with this nonlinear one, which is more way difficult ... specially how to face to squared terms ...

Comment: By the way, what you have here is not the minimal surface equation I believe.

Comment: seems like it is, you can write it in form as :   $$A =  \int \int (1 + u_x^2 + u_y^2)^{1/2} dx dy $$  and according to : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_surface#cite_note-Meusnier1785-3 it should be

Comment: @nicoguaro I am in process of assembling eq.8 from paper u suggested, is there any way how to do it efficiently? Currently, I first assemble $\gamma$ and then in next loop $f_{ij}$ from eq. 7. I am really grateful for any suggestion ...

Comment: In Matlab, I think that you can use vectorized operation. Let's continue in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27218/minimal-surface-fdm).

Comment: @nicoguaro I do not have 20 points to continue on chat :/ .. any other suggestions? would you mind email/ what's up/ viber/ skype or any other of alternatives?

Comment: Yes, I do. You can do operations like the ones described in Eq 8 for interior points, the first term is something like ``(u(2:n-1, 2:n-1) - u(1:n-2, 2:n-1)).^2;``

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fast implementation using sparse matrices and sparse Jacobian estimation:

```matlab
% define square domain [-1,1] x [-1,1]
n = 51;
x=linspace(-1,1,n);
y=x;
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,x);

% build finite differences operators
dx=x(2)-x(1);
e=ones(n,1);
d0x=ones(n,1);
grad = spdiags([-e 0*e e],-1:1,n,n)/2/dx;
% use Kronecker product to build matrix of d/dx and d/dy
gradx = kron(grad,speye(n,n));
grady = kron(speye(n,n),grad);
lap = spdiags([e -2*e e],-1:1,n,n)/dx^2;
% use Kronecker product to build matrix of d/dx^2 and d/dy^2
lapx = kron(lap,speye(n,n));
lapy = kron(speye(n,n),lap);

% Dirichlet boundary condition
bdy = find(X(:)==x(1) | X(:)==x(end) | Y(:)==y(1) | Y(:)==y(end));
cnd = 0.5*sign(sin(4*(X(bdy)+Y(bdy))));

% initial value of iterate
f0 = zeros(n^2,1)

opt = optimoptions("fsolve","Algorithm","trust-region",...
    "JacobPattern",lapy+lapx+grady*gradx,"display","iter");

f = fsolve(@(f) fun(f,gradx,grady,lapx,lapy,bdy,cnd),f0,opt);

surf(x,x,reshape(f,n,n),"facecolor","interp")

function out=fun(f,gradx,grady,lapx,lapy,bdy,cnd)
    fx = gradx*f;
    fy = grady*f;
    % equation of mininal surface. Surface is the graph of z=f(x,y)
    % inside domain
    out = (1+fy.^2).*(lapx*f)+(1+fx.^2).*(lapy*f)-2*fx.*fy.*(gradx*(grady*f));
    % at the boundary
    out(bdy) = f(bdy)-cnd;
end
```

[image]